# CSS class not being applied at all in IE7-8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

`<!DOCTYPE html>` has been set, and `html5shim.js` has been included in the `<head>` of each page.

I have the CSS:

```
.height_fix_container > * { margin:0; background:#fff url(../images/bg.jpg) top left no-repeat; min-height: 400px; }
.height_fix_container > *:first-child { background:#fff; } /*Good eye! But the problem still exists*/
```

...being applied to this code in the middle of the page:

```
...
<div class="height_fix_container">
    <div>Content box 1</div>
    <div>Content box 2</div>
</div>
...
```

In every browser other than IE7 and 8, the CSS selectors work great. However, in IE `Content box 1` recognizes the selector but `Content box 2` completely ignores it. I'm checking this with the built in Developer Tools in IE.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: You didn't test it in IE9, did you?

Comment: This would be really, really, really easy to solve if there was a live page to look at. With IE8 open on your page, hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools. Which "Document Mode"/"Browser Mode"?

Comment: Wish I could, it's on a test environment at the company I work for. Let me see if I can duplicate the problem somewhere else for you to view. `Browser mode: IE8` `Document Mode: IE8 Standards`

Answer (score 3):

In IE you need to have a DOCTYPE declared in order for it to recognize the first-child selector.

```
<!DOCTYPE .......>
```

You're also missing a # infront of the 'fff' in the second class definition. It doesn't affect the code at all, just a syntactical edit.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: I didn't read your answer before writing my own, but you're saying the same thing as me. Note that IE9 will have the same problem (it's not "IE8 & earlier").

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> has already been set, this HTML is in the middle of the page. Good eyes on the # before the fff, but the problem still exists.

Comment: How are you linking the stylesheet to the page? Is it recognizing any of the styles at all?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` will trigger Standards Mode in at least IE6 and onwards.

Comment: It's recognizing all other styles.

Comment: I'm not sure what the background image looks like, but you have the same background color for both class definitions. Try to change the background color in the > *:first-child definition to a different color (#FF0000) to see if the style is not being recognized.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 is very particular with `:first-child` and might be choking on the `*` before it.

Perhaps you can add another style to the sheet:

```
 .height_fix_container > div:first-child { background:#fff; }
```

*Untested*

Comment: It's actually selecting the :first-child without a problem. It's the other DIV that is ignoring the selector. Also, there are other instances where things other than DIVs are being used (FIGURE, ARTICLE, etc), which is why I used the *.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is being displayed in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Your description and CSS is making me quite certain.

The most likely cause is that you don't have a valid doctype as the *very first line*. Add this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you do already have a doctype, there are other things can cause Quirks Mode.

Once you fix this, `background:fff` will no longer work. You need `background:#fff`. The `#` is important.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/a256R/ - similar selectors - work in IE7 and IE8 (first div is green, second is red). Problem is somewhere else (background image url, other rules etc.).